# is there any shorthand method to handle loops if you know exactly how much times a loop needs to be executed

Tags: php, loops

I have no problem in using loops but sometimes it really feels odd to use an separate variable just to count how many times loop has been executed especially when you know exactly how many times the loop needs to be executed just for example:

```
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++) echo "<input type='text' name='abc[]'/><br/>\n";
```

Now here I know exactly that the loop needs to do same thing 5 times so why to use an extra variable `$i`,*initialize it,check condition each time and update it*.

is there any short hand method such as:

```
execute(5){
echo "<input type='text' name='abc[]'/><br/>\n";}
```

which simply knows it have to do some work for a fixed number of times.

Currently i am familiar with these loops

- for()
- foreach()
- while()
  &
- do while()

Please let me know if there exist any other.

Comment: There is not, but you could make a function to do so.

Comment: yes ofcource i can make a function but yet its an waste of execution time(even thou its negligible)

Comment: @DigitalChris That misses the point, he doesn't want to do just the string function, he wants a generic function to loop a given amount of times.

Answer (score 2):

Shortest way I can think of is using the while loop.

```
<?php
$i=5;
while($i--){
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thats quite a smart way thanks for your idea but it isn't what i am looking for..

Comment: Right and what you are looking for does not exist in PHP. Don't worry about the little variables, worry more about your overall architecture.

Comment: @Subhanker If you worry about that variable (`$i`) just unset it after the loop: `unset($i);`

Comment: This is actually poor practice, it's called a "magic number". What does 5 mean? why 5? it should be a named constant.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for unfortunately doesn't exist.

But the idea of loops without extra variables is really great I will suggest you to submit an Idea on [PHP official site](http://www.php.net/) So that they can create such methods in next release.

Answer (score 0):

When the number of loops is known, the best option is the for loop. As your example shows, it will loop until the desired number of times, in your case 5 (the original loop and goes up 5 times for a total of 6, unless you have 7 entries in which case the 6 is your required value).

Foreach comes in handy particularly for arrays.

A while loop is used when calling information from a database.

@DigitalChris recommends str_repeat, but I think the for loop is clearer in terms of code. The best solution isn't always to be quick to do right away, it's often to be able to make quick changes if the need comes. Personal opinion, anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your help but Thats well known to me ,I am looking to an easier/short hand way of repeating stuff without wasting memry/execution time on useless stuff..

Comment: PHP is not meant to be micro-optimized.

Comment: A for loop is always cleaner to read and troubleshoot, and also allows you to comment, saves you time if you need to edit the function and hand. Not knowing the case, I would suggest a for loop. However, for short strings, the str_repeat is a good option.

Answer (score -1):

Not as far as I know. The closest I can come is `str_repeat` but of course that's not what you're looking for. You could try writing a function that accepts an integer and a callable and roll your own. However, I recommend just using for loops in case other programmers have to read your code. If I need to do something five times I write:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

That way the five is literally in the code and it's nice and readable. Your own `for` loop has a 6 instead of a 5, which to me makes it less readable.

As Jessica pointed out in the comments to this answer, you should really not hard code digits either way, you're better off using a constant or a parameter of some kind. That way you can improve readability even more and have a single place where you can change all occurrences of that particular "5" with some other number.

Comment: That's the way his code is too, except it has a 6 instead of a 5.

Comment: ...and he wants to do something 5 times, not 6, which is why I'm giving OP the tip so they can increase legibility.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. His code is exactly the same as yours, it's just as "legible" that it's a 6, not a 5. Those numbers are examples, not his actual request.

Also, this is actually poor practice, it's called a "magic number". What does 5 mean? why 5? it should be a named constant.

Comment: Of course it's an example, I get that OP isn't looking for doing something 5 times. The thing is I got confused when I read his `for` loop. I thought he'd made a mistake and written a `for` loop that does something 6 times when he wanted to do it 5 times. Legibility is good and better legibility is even better.

Comment: @Jessica you're right about the constant, edited my answer to reflect that.